# Is Function execution continues in web api, when client is closed?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

Scenario: After making a call from client to web api, and client is closed(like browser is closed) will the functionality continues on the server? As there is no client to accept the response, what will be the situation? will the functionality stops as the client is closed, How it happens? If the functionality continues, how to stop it? As no one will be willing utilize the resources for a closed client.

Comment: The `WCF` tag contradicts the other tags and the content of the question. So I removed it. If you feel it _is_ required. Please add it back but explain in your question why WCF is part of this question/answer.

Comment: To your question: you might want to read [this](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50329618/should-i-always-add-cancellationtoken-to-my-controller-actions).

Comment: In what direction is your application scenario, you can read the reply content of this post, it may be helpful to you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772597/detecting-async-client-disconnect-in-asp-net-mvc